# Predict multiple dependent variables in a neural network in R (caret, train, neuralnet): wrong model type for classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, r-caret, training-data

I am using the function `train()` (from the `caret` package) to train a neural network coming from the package `neuralnet`.

Before running the training of the neural network, these are the data frames to work in the `predict` function and other elements that need to be included (as the activation function). Simply copy/paste the next code to prepare to run the training.

```
train_df <- structure(list(DC1 = c(4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 11, 11, 6, 8, 5, 9, 10, 
6, 11, 15, 13, 17, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 13, 15), DC2 = c(10, 
7, 11, 11, 12, 8, 10, 5, 8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 13, 16, 13, 16, 7, 8, 
13, 12, 9, 13, 13, 15, 13), DC3 = c(9, 8, 10, 10, 9, 11, 9, 6, 
9, 8, 9, 7, 7, 13, 14, 11, 9, 11, 12, 13, 12, 10, 12, 11, 11, 
11), DC4 = c(12, 9, 11, 11, 8, 13, 12, 7, 9, 10, 8, 8, 10, 12, 
12, 10, 10, 13, 11, 12, 11, 14, 14, 11, 13, 14), DC5 = c(14, 
12, 9, 14, 10, 14, 13, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 14, 12, 14, 16, 
14, 12, 14, 11, 16, 15, 11, 19, 17), DC6 = c(10, 12, 10, 18, 
11, 15, 16, 12, 12, 11, 13, 13, 14, 16, 19, 19, 22, 15, 14, 15, 
14, 14, 16, 15, 20, 23), DC7 = c(20, 21, 12, 17, 15, 19, 17, 
11, 16, 15, 17, 15, 15, 25, 22, 20, 18, 15, 13, 20, 20, 19, 24, 
17, 29, 24), DC8 = c(21, 15, 20, 17, 21, 17, 19, 15, 21, 14, 
20, 19, 15, 30, 26, 24, 22, 16, 19, 21, 32, 27, 23, 28, 33, 30
), DC9 = c(28, 26, 22, 17, 23, 16, 18, 18, 18, 22, 25, 25, 23, 
32, 27, 32, 27, 22, 24, 22, 29, 33, 26, 21, 31, 30), DC10 = c(30, 
33, 23, 43, 26, 30, 22, 34, 23, 23, 36, 37, 29, 29, 30, 50, 31, 
25, 27, 23, 30, 36, 35, 38, 18, 33)), row.names = c(165L, 167L, 
168L, 172L, 174L, 176L, 177L, 236L, 246L, 260L, 263L, 277L, 280L, 
281L, 282L, 302L, 315L, 321L, 322L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 335L, 336L, 
339L, 340L), class = "data.frame")

pre_mdl_df <- structure(list(dim = c(26L, 10L), bc = NULL, yj = NULL, et = NULL, 
    invHyperbolicSine = NULL, mean = NULL, std = NULL, ranges = structure(c(4, 
    17, 5, 16, 6, 14, 7, 14, 9, 19, 10, 23, 11, 29, 14, 33, 16, 
    33, 18, 50), .Dim = c(2L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("DC1", 
    "DC2", "DC3", "DC4", "DC5", "DC6", "DC7", "DC8", "DC9", "DC10"
    ))), rotation = NULL, method = list(range = c("DC1", "DC2", 
    "DC3", "DC4", "DC5", "DC6", "DC7", "DC8", "DC9", "DC10"), 
        ignore = character(0)), thresh = 0.95, pcaComp = NULL, 
    numComp = NULL, ica = NULL, wildcards = list(PCA = character(0), 
        ICA = character(0)), k = 5, knnSummary = function (x, 
        ...) 
    UseMethod("mean"), bagImp = NULL, median = NULL, data = NULL, 
    rangeBounds = c(0, 1)), class = "preProcess")

softplus <- function(x) log(1+exp(x)) # activation function

tune.grid.neuralnet <- expand.grid(
  layer1 = c(1:5), # first hidden layer, from 1 to 5 neurons
  layer2 = c(0:5), # second hidden layer, from 0 to 5 neurons
  layer3 = c(0:5)  # third hidden layer, from 0 to 5 neurons
)
```

Now I run the training of the neural network:

```
model <- train(DC1 + DC2 + DC3 ~., data = predict(pre_mdl_df, train_df), 
               method = "neuralnet", 
               tuneGrid = tune.grid.neuralnet,
               metric = "RMSE",
               stepmax = 100000,
               learningrate = 0.01,  
               threshold = 0.01,
               act.fct = softplus,
               trControl = caret::trainControl (
                 method = "repeatedcv", 
                 number = 2,               # Number of folds of the cv
                 repeats = 1,              # Number of cv repetitions
                 verboseIter = TRUE,
                 savePredictions = TRUE,
                 allowParallel = TRUE))
```

It takes some time (around 1 min in my computer) but finally it results in creating the model.

### Problem: Error: wrong model type for classification

However, [based on this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876146/predict-multiple-dependent-variables-in-r-linear-model-as-example/74876267#74876267), in order to predict separating per dependent variables, I should use `cbind()` in the formula (in the next code I only changed the first line):

```
model <- train(cbind(DC1, DC2, DC3) ~., data = predict(pre_mdl_df, train_df), 
               method = "neuralnet", 
               tuneGrid = tune.grid.neuralnet,
               metric = "RMSE",
               stepmax = 100000,
               learningrate = 0.01,  
               threshold = 0.01,
               act.fct = softplus,
               trControl = caret::trainControl (
                 method = "repeatedcv", 
                 number = 2,               # Number of folds of the cv
                 repeats = 1,              # Number of cv repetitions
                 verboseIter = TRUE,
                 savePredictions = TRUE,
                 allowParallel = TRUE))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: wrong model type for classification
```

- Where is the problem?
- How can I replicate the process [explained in the previous linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876146/predict-multiple-dependent-variables-in-r-linear-model-as-example/74876267#74876267) with a neural network?

Comment: Your first model works great. Is there a reason that you felt compelled to redo it?  You don't need `cbind` for the `neuralnet` package.

Comment: Thanks @Kat, if you go to the link in my post, you will see that I am facing some problems when predicting more than one dependent variable (in this case DC1, DC2 and DC3). If I use `train(formula = DC1 + DC2 + DC3 ~., data = predict(pre_mdl_df, train_df)` and then I use `predict()`, I only get 1 result instead of the value of the three variables. If I were using `train(cbind(DC1, DC2, DC3) ~., data = predict(pre_mdl_df, train_df)` I would expect to predict the three variables. Any idea on how I can predict all the dependent variables?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. Odd, when you run `neuralnet` outside of `caret` there is no such problem. I think I've cycled through all of the parameters to see if it's a setting you do or don't have. I found nothing amiss. You could manually implement the features of `caret`, I suppose.